# Reflections Library , unable to find any classes within my package

Tags: java, reflection, package, reflections

I am attempting to use the reflections library to get access to classes inside a package in my project. As per suggestions from the question below.

[Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection)

When running my method, size() on my set  0 is shown.

```
 List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
       classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
       classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner())
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))            
         .filterInputsBy(newFilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("com.ruperts.java.Commands"))));


        Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

        System.out.println(classes.size());
```

I also tried setting the prefix to "" as per comment in other questions - still shows as no classes were found.

*if anyone wonders a the simplest way to get the default package is having the prefix be an empty String -> "".*

Is the issue with my package name?